# Why selectList doesn't refresh my property in controler extension

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm newbie in Salesforce so it can be obvious but I'm stuck on this problem.

My extended controler's property SelectedProductType is not updated. Do you know why?

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="opportunityProductEntryExtension" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="search">
                Select an item:
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:selectList id="monId" value="{!SelectedProductType}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!ProductTypeOptions}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:outputPanel >
                Item selected is {!SelectedProductType}
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Extended controler:

```
public with sharing class opportunityProductEntryExtension {

    public string SelectedProductType {get;set;}

    public List<SelectOption> ProductTypeOptions{
        get{
             List<SelectOption> options = new List<Selectoption>();

            options.add(new SelectOption('Product 1','Product 1'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Product 2','Product 2'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Product 3','Product 3'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Product 4','Product 4'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Product 5','Product 5'));

            return options;
        }
    }    

    public opportunityProductEntryExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       // Used to check if outputPanel can show SelectedProductType
       //SelectedProductType = 'Product 0'; // used to check if outputPanel can show 
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You never save and requery your data, and you also don't rerender any part of the page, so the data displayed will never change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `actionsupport` tag here

```
<apex:selectList id="monId" value="{!SelectedProductType}" multiselect="false" size="1">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!ProductTypeOptions}"/>
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="panel" />
</apex:selectList>
 <apex:outputPanel id="panel">
      Item selected is {!SelectedProductType}
</apex:outputPanel>
```

This will refresh(rerender) the value and you will get updated value.

Comment: This is what I was missing. Thanks. One more point: when ma page is created, "Project 1" is initially visually selected but 'panel' is not updated. Is there a way to do it? I know that I can manually update 'SelectedProductType' in 'ProductTypeOptions.get' but I'd hope a more elegant solution.